# mongoose query to insert doc in not exist?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB collection is Like below:

```
[
    { x: "a", t: 1, s: 'old' },
    { x: "a", t: 3, s: 'old' },
    { x: "b", t: 1, s: 'old' },
    { x: "b", t: 4, s: 'old' }
]
```

I have also an array as below:

```
const list = [
    { x: "a", t: 1, s: 'new' },
    { x: "a", t: 2, s: 'new' },
    { x: "b", t: 2, s: 'new' },
    { x: "b", t: 3, s: 'new' },
]
```

now I want to insert

> list

array into mongo collection in a way that :

- if the item that will be inserted, exists in the collection, then don't insert it.
- if the item that will be inserted, exists in the collection, then insert it.

the final result should be as below:

```
[
    { x: "a", t: 1, s: 'old' },
    { x: "a", t: 2, s: 'new' },
    { x: "a", t: 3, s: 'old' },
    { x: "b", t: 1, s: 'old' },
    { x: "b", t: 2, s: 'new' },
    { x: "b", t: 3, s: 'new' },
    { x: "b", t: 4, s: 'old' }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update query with [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#upsert) option,

```
const list = [
  { x: "a", t: 1, s: 'new' },
  { x: "a", t: 2, s: 'new' },
  { x: "b", t: 2, s: 'new' },
  { x: "b", t: 3, s: 'new' }
]
```

The first option, execute each query loop through,

- create a function for the update query

  - query to match `x` and `t` field
  - `$setOnInsert` set fields only if this is a new document
  - `upsert: true` to update the document if already exists
- loop `list` array of documents and call update query function

```
async function updateQuery(doc){
  await YourModel.updateOne(
    { x: doc.x, t: doc.t },
    { $setOnInsert: doc },
    { upsert: true }
  );
}

list.forEach(function(doc) {
  updateQuery(doc);
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QvIFq8d6g4l)

---

The second option, use [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method to execute all update queries in a transaction,

- `updateQuery` function to create a updateOne query
- loop `list` array of documents and call `updateQuery` function and construct an array of update queries
- call `bulkWrite` query function

```
function updateQuery(doc){
  return {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { x: doc.x, t: doc.t },
      update: { $setOnInsert: doc },
      upsert: true
    }
  };
}

let bulkWriteQuery = [];
list.forEach(function(doc) {
  bulkWriteQuery.push(updateQuery(doc));
});

await YourModel.bulkWrite(bulkWriteQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the `map` function to iterate through the list.
- Then you can use the mongoose `findOne` to check whether the item already exists in the collection.
- If the item is not there `save` it to the collection and continue with the iteration. (The list should be an array of objects of the mongoose schema you are using)

```
list.map((item) => {
    if(!Collection.findOne({x: item.x, t: item.t})) {
        try {
            await item.save();
        } catch(error) {
            //handle the error
        }
    }
});
```